# Construct a method name for customer object dynamically

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer-attribute, varien

I have a Magento website with four stores. For each customer different cut off time will be assigned for each store.

User is restricted to add product from only one store at a time. When user come to check out page I have to get the cut off time for the store from which he added the product.

I managed to get the store code.

Customer attributes for store cut off time are as below

```
`delivery_cutoff_time_abc` // here abc is the store code
`delivery_cutoff_time_def` // here def is the store code
`delivery_cutoff_time_ghi` // here ghi is the store code
`delivery_cutoff_time_jkl` // here jkl is the store code
```

Based on products added to cart I got the Store code whether it its`abc` or `def` or so.

Now I have to get the value from customer object as below

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customer->getDeliveryCutoffTimeAbc();
```

For doing this I have store code as below

`$storeCode = "abc";`

I have to use dynamic as below

```
$customer->getDeliveryCutoffTime.$storeCode();
```

It doesn't get the value. How may I make it dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$storeCode = ucfirst("abc");

$function = "getDeliveryCutoffTime".$storeCode;

$customer->$function();
```

Comment: Sorry to say that I tried this and its not working

Comment: ok try print_r($customer->getData()); and see if you are getting value for DeliveryCutoffTime or not

Comment: yes I am getting it and if use `$customer->getDeliveryCutoffTimeAbc();` I am getting the value too

Comment: strange,it should work. can you post here your complete code file?

Comment: really sorry to say its working, I formed function name as `$functionName = 'getDeliveryLeadTime'.$storeCode.'()';` and called like `$cutOffTime = $customer->$functionName`

Comment: They way you have done it, you are including the `()` in your `$functionName` string. You shouldn't. You should add it in the call itself, so `$cutOffTime = $customer->$functionName()` like the answer is suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, this can also be done like this:

```
$storeCode = "abc";
$customer->{"getDeliveryCutoffTime" . ucfirst($storeCode)}();
```

These Magento "magic" getter methods call the method `getData()` eventually. So `getDeliveryCutoffTimeAbc()` will result in a call to `getData("delivery_cutoff_time_abc")`.

So you could also call this right away:

```
$storeCode = "abc";
$customer->getData("delivery_cutoff_time_" . $storeCode);
```